# Fields_for dynamic label

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fields-for

I have dynamic form which has a set of values. I created a partial which contains text fields which I display. Next to each of them I would like to display a label containing the title of the text. For instance First Name, and Last Name would not be known previously. How do I go about doing that?
It seems that I cannot access the attributes directly. But when I use the label field, the variable name in the label is displayed not the actual value.

Comment: Could you try to explain what you want to accomplish better? Maybe give an example? I have tried to understand in order to help you but I can't understand what you need.

Comment: I have an object which has a one-to-many relation with a set of Dynamic Fields {Name,Value}. When a user is updating the dynamic fields I want to display the name of the fields as the actual label instead of the hardcoded label. Or a predetermined String value. The dynamic form is inside a partial and all data.
Snippets:

_form.erb
<% f.fields_for :entity_values do |builder| %>
      <%= render "entity_value_fields", :f => builder%>
  <% end % 
_entity_value_fields.erb
    <%= f.label :name %> {label needs to be the dynamic name of that value}
    <%= f.text_field :value %>
    ...

Answer (score 6):

Well! This was a reflection of how new I am to rails. You can do this by using `f.object.{attr_name}` and that worked.

Comment: How do you use this? what would be the object in your example?

Answer (score 5):

`f.object.{attr_name}` didn't work for me, but `f.object[:attr_name]` did.

Comment: `f.object.first_name` or `attr_name = 'first_name'; f.object.send(attr_name)` will work. `f.object.{attr_name}` is invalid Ruby syntax.

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
f.object.send(attr_name)
```

That would be the Rubyish way.

Comment: Can you explain this better?

Comment: All form builders have a method called `object` which returns the object which the form is wrapping, typically an ActiveRecord model, say person. We then call `send` on that person to send it a message, so `person.send(:name)` is the same as `person.name`. As you can see using `send` means we do not need to hardcode the attribute (e.g last_name) which we want to display as our label. So in the above case `attr_name` can be any string, either last_name, first_name, whatever.