# How to display dynamic content in rails label without using javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, view

I can't find how to display a dynamic label in Rails, i've tried using the `:value => show_name` property but it didn't work, it only displays `Show name`. Here is the view code

```
<p>
   <div class="control-group">
           <%= f.label :show_name, :value => :show_name, :class => 'control-label' %> 
           <%= #this next line fails with undefined method `show_name' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuiler>
              #f.label f.send :show_name, :class => 'control-label'
           %> 
       <div class="controls">
           <%= f.text_field :variable_value, :class => 'text_field' %> 
           <%= f.hidden_field :variable_id, :class => 'text_field' %> 
       <%= f.hidden_field :show_name, :class => 'text_field' %> 
       </div>
   </div>
<p>
```

and if needed here is the show_name definition inside my model.

```
  def show_name
    Variable.find_by_id(self.variable_id).name
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so i end up finding a solution that is very `DRY`, thank to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392837/fields-for-dynamic-label/11982752#comment18404465_11982752). And the only thing im going to do is explain a lit bit more what to do:

First we are going to asume the most complex case in which we have nested forms and so we are using `fields_for` inside a `form_for` method:

```
  <!-- f represents the form from `form_for` -->
  <%= f.fields_for :nested_model do |builder| %>
    <p>
      <div class="control-group">

         <!-- here we are just calling a helper method to get things DRY -->

         <%= builder.label return_value_of_symbol(builder,:show_name), :class => 'control-label' %> 
         <div class="controls">
            <%= builder.text_field :variable_value, :class => 'text_field' %> 
            <%= builder.hidden_field :variable_id, :class => 'text_field' %> 
         </div>
      </div>
    </p>
  <% end %>
```

Note that we included the builder object(as specified in the fields_for call) in the parameters of our helper.

In our helper we define the `return_value_of_symbol` function

```
  def return_value_of_symbol(obj,sym)
    # And here is the magic, we need to call the object method of fields_for
    # to obtain the reference of the object we are building for, then call the
    # send function so we send a message with the actual value of the symbol 
    # and so we return that message to our view.  
    obj.object.send(sym)
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `label_tag`, put the show_name on a instance variable on your controller and use like this:

```
<%= label_tag @show_name, nil, :class => 'control-label' %>
```

EDIT:

On your `application_helper.rb`, create a helper method similar to this one:

```
def show_name(name)
  content_tag(:label, name, :class => 'control-label')
end
```

Then you can use the `show_name(name)` on your views like this:

```
<%= show_name(@name) %>
```

Just remember to populate the `@name variable`.

Comment: would this be DRY? i would need to add this to every definition in the controller, or at least index and show or anyone else that uses _form.html.erb, i will need to use `<%=` in any case i presume

Comment: Use a helper then. Put the code in a helper and use it in all of your views.

Comment: you mean like create an alternative to label_tag or somehow return the string of the variable?

Comment: Yeah. On your application_helper, create a method that receives a name and dinamically create a label using `content_tag`.

Comment: im still not getting how to do that, im doing `<%= content_tag(:label,:show_name, :class => 'control-label') %>` but is the same thing

Comment: I added an example to my answer. Take a look and see if it helps.

Comment: populating `@name` would mean to do something in the controller? because we would be where we started

Comment: The variable have to be populated somewhere. You can use the query on the helper too.

Comment: Hey i just found a way without doing a search in the model, hopefully DRY solution, let me know what do you think.